# Push notifications on iOS - weird situation

Tags: javascript, ios, parse-platform, push-notification

I'm trying to set up push notifications with parse server.

I download this program called "apnTester" and with it, if I feed in the device token and dev Certificate, it sends the notifications. **However**, if I set the same file to my parse server, the notifications don't work. Here's the code I used:

```
var api = new ParseServer({
  databaseURI: databaseUri || 'myURI',
  verbose: true,
  cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
  appId: process.env.APP_ID || 'myAppId',
  masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY || 'myMasterKey', //Add your master key here. Keep it secret!
  push: {
      ios: [
        {
          cert: '/cloud/appDev.cer',
          bundleId: 'myBundleID',
          production: false
        },
        {
          pfx: '/cloud/myPush.p12', // Prod PFX or P12
          bundleId: 'myBundleID',  
          production: true // Prod
        }
      ]
    },
  serverURL: process.env.SERVER_URL || 'myServerURL/parse' 
});

Parse.serverURL = process.env.SERVER_URI || 'myServerURL/parse';
```

But what's interesting is when I call the following code, it results with "Incremented":

```
PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("sendPush", withParameters: ["recipient": "oA8GXqJpWX"], block: {
            (result: AnyObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

            if ( error === nil) {
                println("Incremented")
                println("Result is \(result)")
            }
            else if (error != nil) {
                println("Error")
                println(error)
            }
        })
```

Comment: you can go with APNS server instead of parse..

Comment: Double check the environment, the certificate is for sandbox or production ?

Comment: @Janmenjaya well I uploaded both and I'm testing on a dev phone and a production phone. The dev phone works with apn tester, but doesn't work with parse